# Xamarin.Forms iOS image cannot show from file path

Tags: image, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

In my Xamarin.Forms app, I have copied some files into my device and those files don't have an extension. Actually those are image files. now I want to show those images in my UI. For that I am doing like this in my shared project.

```
string path = DependencyService.Get<IFileManager>().GetLocalFilePath(attachmentName);
image.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(path);
```

Both in UWP and Android these images are showing perfectly but in iOS. This is the `path` that I am getting for iOS.

> "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/74FC64B4-3B37-4240-966B-2DB1CAFF0E45/Documents/Library/Databases/5302"

5302 is my file name and it has no extension. In iOS I cannot see any image. Please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Put all your images in the Resources-folder of your iOS-project and it should work!

Comment: I want to download those files and save in the device. So I don't think I can add them to the resource folder. I need to get those images from the server when the app installs